# React Semantic-ui How to handle dropdown onclick with additional parameter

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using react semantic ui dropdown and want to handle onclick event on my dropdown. consider i have this method to handle

```
handleClick = (e, {value }) => this.setState({id: value })
```

then i can call with this

```
 <Dropdown
     selection
     options={myOptions}
     placeholder='I change value on keyboard navigation'
     onClick={this.handleClick} />
```

but in some circumstances i want to call handleClick with additional parameter, i've tried this

```
<Dropdown
     selection
     options={myOptions}
     placeholder='I change value on keyboard navigation'
     onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,idx)} />
```

and change my handler to `handleClick = (e, {value },idx) => this.setState({id: value })` but it seems not working. What am i doing wrong or any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think this part is not executing like this

```
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,idx)}
```

It should be change to this

```
onClick={(idx) => this.handleClick.bind(this,idx)}
```

In React when we have to pass the arguments with function on click , then we have to add arrow notation like above.
If this help doesn't work for you then I think you have to change your binding
Then Following code will help you

Change `onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,idx)}` to this

`onClick={(e, e.target.value, idx) => this.handleClick(e, e.target.value, idx)}`

And also change

`handleClick = (e, {value },idx) => this.setState({id: value })`

to this

`handleClick = (e, value, idx) => this.setState({id: value })`